# Linux Mint (LMDE) suddenly crashed and won't boot again

Tags: boot, crash, system-recovery

I was working on my linux machine earlier today and when I was in the middle of updating my java packages through the package manager and installing coffee script, my windows started not working and closed down. I didn't think much of it and kept on working in TexStudio and finishing my hand in for this week, saved it and closed it and closed my browser and thought

- "Hey, maybe it just needs a reboot!"

I then rebooted the computer, chose my Linux Mint partition and here is where it gets weird. The only thing I see when I boot is the Linux Mint logo and after that the screen is just completely black and all I can see is a few light grey pixels in the top left of my screen. I looks like a terminal cursor, but it's not flashing and nothing happens when I press my keyboard.

The good news here is that I can boot the Linux partition in recovery mode, but I don't really know what to do from there. Is there a way to revert some of the latest changes back to how it was set up yesterday? Or am I completely lost here? I would love to have it up and running again, because it's my favorite development environment but I do not know much about the kernel and how it works.

If you need more info, please tell me how to get it and I will post it here.

[image: lspci output]

The `lspci` output is seen above

Also I noticed the the message `ideapad_laptop: Unknown Event: 1` appears on the screen about every 10 seconds. I cannot press `Ctrl + Alt + F1` to enter tty from non-recovery mode

Comment: Can you post the output of `lspci`?  I have a hunch...

Comment: Can you switch to a tty using Ctrl+Alt+F1 (from the black screen, not the recovery console)? Are you _sure_ you only updated java packages and in no way touched your graphics driver? On the off chance, also try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mdm` to reconfigure the login manager, that has a small chance of working but is easy and not dangerous. Also, there's no such thing as Debian Mint 16. Are you using the regular Mint (which does have a version 16 but is not based on Debian) or the Debian edition (LMDE)?

Comment: Sorry for the inaccuracy - it's of course LDME :)

Comment: LMDE -.-' damn my fingers!

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I have a dual boot with Windows 7 and LMDE. When I try to boot from the LMDE partition like normal, it will load the screen with the Mint logo, then it goes to a screen with just a small line in the top left, like a text cursor but it doesn't blink. I am unsure what I did to cause this but it started after I deleted some files on the Windows partition.

Comment: @MartinFuddlefingers - I have posted a solution below. Hope it helps :) if not, try writing again with some more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that what happened was I install the boot sequence (or whatever it is called) on `sdb1` or something similar and not on `sda` where the boot flag was set. So what I did was I booted linux from a live USB and re installed my linux mint, and put the boot sequence to be installed on `sda` and set the boot flag there through `gdisk`.

After that I installed `grub` from the terminal and ran `sudo update-grub` and tadaa, my problems were fixed and the `GRUB-loader` now found the linux boot loader and the windows 7 boot loader :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with LMDE5 on two computers and couldn't figure out what was occurring. After backing up all my files using the CLI, I'm now using Debian Bullseye. If I want the display to look like LMDE5, I just select the cinnamon desktop.